# Strange behaviour of callback function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to solve problem with `filter` array function in Typescript, code below:

```js
type Tag = string

type Args = {
  tags?: Tag[]
}

const func = async (args: Args) => {
  if (args.tags) {
    const entities = [
      { tagId: '1' },
      { tagId: '2' }
    ];
    
    const filtered = entities.filter(entity => args.tags.includes(entity.tagId));
    const mapped = args.tags.map(tag => tag + '_test');  
  }
};
```

This code throws TS2532 error: **Object is possibly undefined** when I try to filter the `entities` array. For some reasons TS interpreter thinks that `args.tags` can be undefined, so `include` function can't be called. But as you see, there is a check above, also the `map` function works fine.

What can be wrong here? Any thoughts are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know that `filter`'s callback runs immediately, so if for example `filter`'s callback ran *later* (let's say on a `setTimeout`), your code *would* crash under a call like this:

```
const a: Args = { tags: [] };
await func(a);
a.tags = undefined;
// Later, the callback runs and accesses 'includes' of the undefined we just set
```

You can either use `!`

```
entity => args.tags!.includes ...
```

Or stash the value in a `const`

```
const tags = args.tags;
if (tags) {
  // ...
  const filtered = entities.filter(entity => tags.includes ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. No it is clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Args = {
  tags?: Tag[] // this means --> tags: Tag[] | undefined
}
```

Use **optional chaining and nullish coalescing** inside `Array.filter()`.

`const filtered = entities.filter(entity => args?.tags?.includes(entity.tagId));`